# Are Jacobi elliptic functions liouvillian?

Tags: functions, special-functions, elliptic-functions

I mean: could a Jacobi elliptic function be expressed in terms of a "*finite number of arithmetic operations (+ – × ÷), exponentials, constants, solutions of
algebraic equations (a generalization of nth roots), and indefinite integrals of such elements*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a proof that the non-constant elliptic functions are not Liouvillian (be careful that the elliptic functions are the inverse of the elliptic integrals).

- The Liouvillian functions $L$ is a set defined recursively :

  > $f(z)  = 1$ and $g(z)  =z$ are in $L$.
  >
  > If $f(z),g(z)$ are in $L$ then
  >
  > - $a f(z)+b g(z)$, $f(z)g(z)$ are in $L$
  > - if $f(z)$ is non-constant then $\exp f(z)$, $\log f(z), 1/f(z)$ are in $L$
  > - $\int f(z)dz$ is in $L$
  > - $h(z)$ is in $L$ if $\sum_{n=0}^d a_n h(z)^n $ is in $L$
- Then Let $M$ be the constants plus the set of almost everywhere analytic functions such that for every sector $$S_{a,\theta,b} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, |z-a| >0,  \text{arg}(e^{i \theta} (z-a)) \in (-b,b)\}$$ there is a sub-sector $S_{a',\theta',b'}\subseteq S_{a,\theta,b}$ such that : $f(z)$ is analytic and injective on $S_{a',\theta',b'}$.

From this you can show by induction that if $f(z) \in L$ then $f(z) \in M$,

and since the elliptic functions (the doubly periodic meromorphic functions that are non-constant) are not in $M$, they are not in $L$ neither.

- If $f(z) \in M$ and non-constant then $1/f(z),\exp f(z),\log f(z)$  are in $M$.
- If $f(z) \not\in M$ then $\sum_{n=0}^d c_n f(z)^n \not\in M$
- If $f(z),g(z) \in M$ then $ af(z)+bg(z), f(z)g(z)$ are in $M$
- A little work shows that if $f(z) \in M$ then  $\int f(z)dz \in M$

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I'll study it up!

Comment: @LoScrondo I changed $M$ a bit because it was unclear what happens for $af(z)+bg(z)$ and $f(z)g(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer found in http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/46/45/455203 (the subject is Differential Galois theory):

> for instance, one obtains some kind of
>   solvability (virtual) for the Galois group whenever one obtains *Liouvillian
>   solutions*, and in this case one says that the differential equation is integrable.
>   This means for example that when one obtains Airy functions, the
>   differential equation is not integrable, while when one obtains Jacobi elliptic
>   functions, the differential equation is integrable

Comment: They are [referring to $y = \int_x^\infty \frac {ds} {\sqrt{4s^3 - g_2s -g_3}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Integral_equation) (i.e. finding $y$ from $x$) not the opposite $x = \int_y^\infty \frac {ds} {\sqrt{4s^3 - g_2s -g_3}}$ which is what you asked

Comment: Could you be more clear? Are you talking about Jacobi or Weierstrass elliptic functions? And what's the difference between the two formulae you've written?

Comment: Every elliptic functions are rational functions in $\wp(z)$ and $\wp'(z)$, so Jacobi or Weierstrass doesn't change anything. And $x = f(y)$ means $y= f^{-1}(x)$ so I'm saying your citation is about $\wp^{-1}(z)$ (which is trivially Liouvillian) not $\wp(z)$

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thanks. Hoping someone will answer in the proper way.

Comment: Well you can prove by induction that the Liouvillian functions are not doubly periodic.

Comment: If I correctly understood, you're saying that the elliptic functions -as a class- aren't liouvillian, but there are some elliptic functions that indeed are.

Comment: No, why do you think there are some Liouvillian elliptic functions ?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Let me start form the beginning: why do you say they're referring to the elliptic integral you wrote?

Comment: Because elliptic integral is not the same as [elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) !! $\wp(z)$ is a doubly periodic meromorphic function (i.e. an elliptic function) and $\wp^{-1}(s) = \int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{4 s^3-a s-b}}$  i.e. $\wp^{-1}(s)$ is an elliptic integral (which is Liouvillian)

Comment: Ok, sure. But why if I read *when one obtains Jacobi elliptic functions* I have to think that what was obtained is the elliptic integral, and not directly an elliptic function?

Comment: Your proof seems fine @user1952009, but I write here in order to reply also to my last comment. Maybe I've encountered a lexical problem - I thought that the solutions of the differential equation *were* elliptic functions, and not that *were expressed in terms of* elliptic functions.

Comment: To use an analogy: elliptic functions are like trigonometric functions (in fact they degenerate to trigonometric functions for certain values of their parameters), and elliptic integrals are like *inverse* trigonometric functions. You wouldn't confuse sine and arcsine, no?